# Where do I put the sqljdbc4.jar file?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, jdbc

I'm new at trying to connect my SQL Server database to my android application. I looked online and found some results to connect it via JDBC. Although I don't 100% understand it, I thought I would give it a shot. I found a website that gives me the code to connect to it (I place it in a java file, I'm guessing since it's java code. My guess the main activity?)

Here's the link: http://www.programcreek.com/2010/05/java-code-for-connecting-ms-sql-server-by-using-sql-server-authentication/

So basically, my main question is, where do I place the file in my project?

Comment: in the `libs` folder, then add it to your build path.

Comment: Do you know if I have to place the code in MainActivity or within that, in the OnCreate?

Comment: do the instantiation stuff in `oncreate()` rest code you may write as an user defined method, which you may call whenever you need.